# CSS Linked Comments

Tags: html, css

How can I do this kind of comments using html + css?

[image]

Best regards

Comment: Sorry but the question is too broad and recommendation based questions are off-topic since you either need to script your app or download one for HTML use.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want them in a web page, not a document like your screenshot, your easiest method is a jquery tool tip plugin.

Here is one example https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

And another http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#demos

There are loads of them, search for *jquery tool tip plugin*

(I have no affiliation with the links)